# Regular expression to match all the files with same pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

Need to write a regular expression which would match all the files having names like:

```
ABCD^^A12397_4^^A12397_5^^ABCServer2^^1^^20190117654345
ABCDE^^A12394567_4^^A165557_5^^ABCServer5^^3^^20180117654345
```

Basically need to match pattern like :

```
Alphabets^^AlphaNumericWithSpecialChracter^^ANWSC^^ANWSC^^Numeric^^Numeric
```

Things i have tried :

```
Regex.IsMatch("ABCD^^A12397_4^^A12397_5^^Server2^^1^^20190117654345", "^ABCD\\^\\^A12397_4\\^\\^A12397_5\\^\\^Server2\\^\\^1\\^\\^20190117654345$");
```

Thanks .

Comment: `@^[A-Z]+\^\^[A-Z0-9_]+\^\^[A-Za-z0-9]+\^\^[A-Za-z0-9]+\^\^[0-9]+\^\^[0-9]+$`

Comment: thanks your reg ex helped me . This works as pe rmy requirement "^[A-Za-z0-9]+\\^\\^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\^\\^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\^\\^[A-Za-z0-9]+\\^\\^[0-9]+\\^\\^[0-9]+$"

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `^[A-Za-z](\^\^[\w_]+){3}(\^\^\d+){2}$`

Explanation:

`[A-Za-z]` = Alphabets

`(\^\^[\w_]+){3}` = `^^AlphaNumericWithSpecialChracter` repeated three times (with special character `_`

`(\^\^\d+){2}` = `^^Numeric` repeated twice

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me to write the exact reg ex.

Comment: @sarveshkushwaha If my answer helped you, you should accept it and optionally upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's build the regular expression step by step:

```
Alphabets^^AlphaNumericWithSpecialChracter^^ANWSC^^ANWSC^^Numeric^^Numeric
```

Assuming

```
Alphabets                       - One or more A..Z or a..z letters          - [A-Za-z]+
AlphaNumericWithSpecialChracter - One or more A..Z, a..z, 0..9 letters or _ - [A-Za-z0-9_]+
ANWSC                           - One or more A..Z, a..z, 0..9 letters      - [A-Za-z0-9]+
Numeric                         - One or more 0..9 letters                  - [0-9]+
```

Now we should start the pattern with `^` anchor, end it with `$` one and combine the chunks with `\^\^` (please, note, *escapement*: we want `^` as a plain *character*, not as an *anchor*):

```
string pattern = 
  @"^[A-Za-z]+\^\^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\^\^[A-Za-z0-9]+\^\^[A-Za-z0-9]+\^\^[0-9]+\^\^[0-9]+$";
```

Or if we want to add readability we can put it as

```
string pattern = string.Join(@"\^\^", 
  "^" +             // String start
  "[A-Za-z]+",      // Alphabets
  "[A-Za-z0-9_]+",  // AlphaNumericWithSpecialChracter
  "[A-Za-z0-9]+",   // ANWSC 
  "[A-Za-z0-9]+",   // ANWSC 
  "[0-9]+",         // Numeric
  "[0-9]+" +        // Numeric 
  "$");             // End of string
```